# C# Updating user details error

Tags: c#, active-directory, syntax-error

I'm trying to update the user properties but I get an error :

> The attribute syntax specified to the directory service is invalid

It happens when I do `CommitChanges()`, this code worked for me before so I don't know what is wrong.

This is the code:

```
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(_ldap);

DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de) { Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(SamAccountName=" + logon_tb.Text + "))" };

SearchResult sr = ds.FindOne();

DirectoryEntry userEntry = sr.GetDirectoryEntry();

try { userEntry.Properties["givenName"].Value = fn_tb.Text; }
catch (Exception) { }

try { userEntry.Properties["sn"].Value = ln_tb.Text; }
catch (Exception) { }

try { userEntry.Properties["displayName"].Value = dispName_tb.Text; }
catch (Exception) { }

try { userEntry.Properties["description"].Value = description_tb.Text; }
catch (Exception) { }

try { userEntry.Properties["physicalDeliveryOfficeName"].Value = office_tb.Text; }
catch (Exception) { }

try { userEntry.Properties["telephoneNumber"].Value = telephone_tb.Text; }
catch (Exception) { }

try { userEntry.Properties["mobile"].Value = mobile_tb.Text; }
catch (Exception) { }

try { userEntry.Properties["title"].Value = jobTitle_tb.Text; }
catch (Exception) { }

try { userEntry.Properties["department"].Value = department_tb.Text; }
catch (Exception) { }

try { userEntry.Properties["postOfficeBox"].Value = poBox_tb.Text; }
catch (Exception) { }

try { userEntry.Properties["homeDirectory"].Value = homeFolder_tb.Text; }
catch (Exception) { }

try { userEntry.Properties["extensionAttribute10"].Value = extAtt10_tb.Text; }
catch (Exception) { }

try { userEntry.Properties["extensionAttribute11"].Value = extAtt11_tb.Text; }
catch (Exception) { }

try { userEntry.Properties["extensionAttribute12"].Value = extAtt12_tb.Text; }
catch (Exception) { }

try { userEntry.Properties["extensionAttribute13"].Value = extAtt13_tb.Text; }
catch (Exception) { }

try { userEntry.Properties["extensionAttribute14"].Value = extAtt14_tb.Text; }
catch (Exception) { }

try { userEntry.Properties["extensionAttribute15"].Value = extAtt15_tb.Text; }
catch (Exception) { }

try { userEntry.Properties["SamAccountName"].Value = logon_tb.Text; }
catch (Exception) { }

try { userEntry.Properties["userPrincipalName"].Value = logonPrincipal_tb.Text; }
catch (Exception) { }

if (pwNeverExpire_cb.Checked)
     userEntry.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = 66048;

userEntry.CommitChanges();
userEntry.Close();
```

Comment: I figured that out, when a textbox was empty I received the error so I made if textbox has a value, it will be updated otherwise the property will be null. thx anyway :)

Comment: You might want to leave an answer what resolved your problem! This would definitely help future visitors. Also, please mark that answer as accepted. Cheers...

Answer (score 0):

```
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(_ldap);
            DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de) { Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(SamAccountName=" + logon_tb.Text + "))" };
            SearchResult sr = ds.FindOne();
            DirectoryEntry userEntry = sr.GetDirectoryEntry();
            if (fn_tb.Text != "")
                userEntry.Properties["givenName"].Value = fn_tb.Text;
            else
                userEntry.Properties["givenName"].Value = null;
            if (ln_tb.Text != "")
                userEntry.Properties["sn"].Value = ln_tb.Text;
            else
                userEntry.Properties["sn"].Value = null;
            if (dispName_tb.Text != "")
                userEntry.Properties["displayName"].Value = dispName_tb.Text;
            else
                userEntry.Properties["displayName"].Value = null;
            if (description_tb.Text != "")
                userEntry.Properties["description"].Value = description_tb.Text;
            else
                userEntry.Properties["description"].Value = null;
            if (office_tb.Text != "")
                userEntry.Properties["physicalDeliveryOfficeName"].Value = office_tb.Text;
            else
                userEntry.Properties["physicalDeliveryOfficeName"].Value = null;
            if (telephone_tb.Text != "")
                userEntry.Properties["telephoneNumber"].Value = telephone_tb.Text;
            else
                userEntry.Properties["telephoneNumber"].Value = null;
            if (mobile_tb.Text != "")
                userEntry.Properties["mobile"].Value = mobile_tb.Text;
            else
                userEntry.Properties["mobile"].Value = null;
            if (jobTitle_tb.Text != "")
                userEntry.Properties["title"].Value = jobTitle_tb.Text;
            else
                userEntry.Properties["title"].Value = null;
            if (department_tb.Text != "")
                userEntry.Properties["department"].Value = department_tb.Text;
            else
                userEntry.Properties["department"].Value = null;
            if (poBox_tb.Text != "")
                userEntry.Properties["postOfficeBox"].Value = poBox_tb.Text;
            else
                userEntry.Properties["postOfficeBox"].Value = null;
            if (homeFolder_tb.Text != "")
                userEntry.Properties["homeDirectory"].Value = homeFolder_tb.Text;
            else
                userEntry.Properties["homeDirectory"].Value = null;
            if (extAtt10_tb.Text != "")
                userEntry.Properties["extensionAttribute10"].Value = extAtt10_tb.Text;
            else
                userEntry.Properties["extensionAttribute10"].Value = null;
            if (extAtt11_tb.Text != "")
                userEntry.Properties["extensionAttribute11"].Value = extAtt11_tb.Text;
            else
                userEntry.Properties["extensionAttribute11"].Value = null;
            if (extAtt12_tb.Text != "")
                userEntry.Properties["extensionAttribute12"].Value = extAtt12_tb.Text;
            else
                userEntry.Properties["extensionAttribute12"].Value = null;
            if (extAtt13_tb.Text != "")
                userEntry.Properties["extensionAttribute13"].Value = extAtt13_tb.Text;
            else
                userEntry.Properties["extensionAttribute13"].Value = null;
            if (extAtt14_tb.Text != "")
                userEntry.Properties["extensionAttribute14"].Value = extAtt14_tb.Text;
            else
                userEntry.Properties["extensionAttribute14"].Value = null;
            if (extAtt15_tb.Text != "")
                userEntry.Properties["extensionAttribute15"].Value = extAtt15_tb.Text;
            else
                userEntry.Properties["extensionAttribute15"].Value = null;
            if (logon_tb.Text != "")
                userEntry.Properties["SamAccountName"].Value = logon_tb.Text;
            else
                userEntry.Properties["SamAccountName"].Value = null;
            if (idNumber_tb.Text != "")
                userEntry.Properties["userPrincipalName"].Value = idNumber_tb.Text;
            else
                userEntry.Properties["userPrincipalName"].Value = null;
            userEntry.CommitChanges();
            userEntry.Close();
```

I did it like that and it worked with no problems.